# Reusing Dynamic Prototypes in UITableViewController With Multi-Level Navigation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm attempting to solve what I'm sure is a common problem.

I've got a UITableViewController hooked up with a storyboard and am using two prototype cells. On the first view of the navigation controller, all the cells load correctly. My problem arises when attempting to push another instance of that UITableViewController onto the navigation stack (albiet with different data).

Because the reuse-identified cells are only associated with the first view in the storyboard and not necessarily the class itself, I'm loosing the ability to resuse those prototype cells and get a predictable `nil` response from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.

How can I still maintain the usage of my prototype cells later in the stack? Is my only solution to wire up a nib with the custom cell in it and populate the table view with that?

My display logic is below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    id toDisplay = [[navPool getObjectsForParent:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([toDisplay isKindOfClass:[Category class]]) {
        Category *currentCategory = toDisplay;
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Category";
        CategoryCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.text = currentCategory.name;
        [cell setCategoryId:currentCategory.categoryId];
        return cell;
    } else {
        if ([toDisplay isKindOfClass:[ListTopic class]]) {
            ListTopic *currentTopic = toDisplay;
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Topic";
            ListTopicCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.textLabel.text = currentTopic.name;
            return cell;
        }
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[CategoryCell class]]) {            
        CategoryCell *cell = (CategoryCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        BrowseViewController *newView = [[BrowseViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain andParent:[cell.categoryId intValue]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
    } else if ([cell isKindOfClass:[ListTopicCell class]]) {
        // push detail view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing exactly what I mentioned I might and created the nibs externally and load them if the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` call doesn't return an object. I'm surprised this question isn't more common, my new code is below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    id toDisplay = [[navPool getObjectsForParent:self.parent] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([toDisplay isKindOfClass:[Category class]]) {

        Category *currentCategory = toDisplay;

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Category";

        CategoryCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (!cell) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CategoryCellView" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = (CategoryCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        cell.categoryName.text = currentCategory.name;
        [cell setCategoryId:currentCategory.categoryId];

        return cell;
    } else {
        if ([toDisplay isKindOfClass:[ListTopic class]]) {

            ListTopic *currentTopic = toDisplay;

            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Topic";

            ListTopicCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            if (!cell) {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TopicCellView" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = (ListTopicCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
            }

            cell.textLabel.text = currentTopic.name;

            return cell;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Whatchu tryna pass hommie?");
    return [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Default"];
}
```